# Вызов приватной функции CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как? В руководстве говориться, что такое можно реализовать, но ничего не сказано, как такие функции вызывать, что-то не доходит, как затем вызвать эту функцию из того же контроллера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вопрос про private функции](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266271/codeigniter-private-functions) на Stack Overflow. Там объясняется момент с private и символом подчеркивания.
А вызывать private функцию можно как и другие:

```
$this->имя_функции()
```